# How do I hide a section of HTML without removing it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, libraries

I want to hide a section of HTML, and stop it being viewable from the webpage itself without removing it. Is this possible in HTML or CSS, or can anyone recommend a Javascript library capable of doing this? The part that needs hiding looks similar to this:

```
<p>text1<strong>text2</strong></p>
```

I don't want it to display on the website but I do want it viewable when looking at the code directly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add a "hidden" class to select the target HTML and use `display: none` in CSS:

HTML:

```
<p class="hidden">text1<strong>text2</strong></p>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

...or you could inline it directly:

```
<p style="display:none">text1<strong>text2</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use css display:none

```
<p style="display: none;">text1<strong>text2</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a visibility property in CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

You could wrap whatever elements you want hidden in a `<div>` and set it's visibility to hidden. This property can also be changed dynamically with Javascript.

You could also look into using jQuery, which has animated `hide()` and `show()` functions

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you need, but you can try commenting it out, like:

```
 <!--<p>text1<strong>text2</strong></p>-->
```

Or, add a class/id then select it and on css:

```
.myhidden{
display: none;
}
<p class="myhidden">text1<strong>text2</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to that section of html and give that class property to be hidden.

Example :

```css
.hidden {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden">
                                <a href="product.html"><img title="Necklace" alt="Necklace" src="image/product/05-necklace-60x60.jpg"></a>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to suggest this recent video by CSS-Tricks that overviews and explains many techniques to hide an element with CSS: [CSS-Tricks Screencast #142: Hiding Things with CSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLokyKj10Gw)